# Developer program from name to company, is it possible?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I am opening a new iOS development company and want to start selling my apps immediately and want my apps to be under a company account, I have been in the process of registering a new company account before and it took 3 months, and it is too much time for me, is it possible to register as individual (which will take around a week) then convert it to company profile.

or if there is a way to start the process of two forms together then move the applications from the individuals (with all its sales and ratings) to the company account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to [convert an individual account to a company one](http://www.zx81.org.uk/computing/opinion/ios-developer-program-from-individual-to-company.html), but I suspect that it takes at least as long as opening a new company account since they're checking pretty much the same things.

I would say that three months to open the company account is unusual. It took me less than two months and many people have theirs fly through in a week or two. But either way, I don't think that there's a sure-fire way of getting through their system any quicker.

Comment: ok what will happen if I changed my company registering location country or closed my company, can I renew my apple developer program as a company with the old one with no problems

Comment: My understanding is that is not possible, though I've not tried it myself and I am not completely sure.